# Grouping Properties C#

Tags: c#

can anyone tell me if it is possible to groupe Properties?

Here is an example of what i mean:

```
public class A
{
    public string test { get; set; }

    public group folder
    {
        public string test2 { get; set; }
    }
}

A a = new A();
a.test = "";
a.folder.test2 = "";
```

I hope you understand what i mean.

I know that i can make a class und put a instance of it in Class A but in this case i dont want to 2 Classes i want 1 Propertie Class with "Subfolders".

Is there any way?

thx

Comment: No, you can't. You need two classes, and a property in the first that returns an instance of the second. *Why* don't you want to do that?

Comment: There is no way to do it in the manner you've shown. There are no any "properties groups" in C#.

Comment: @moller1111 [don't use regions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/53114/101308)

Comment: Thanks, it's not that i don't want to make 2 classes. In my special case i have a class A with ~30 properties filled from a xml i only want to group tham because its easier to read. But i dont want(need) a instance of a class B without the class A. It's not really a big deal. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible (*inner class* implementation) emulation:

```
public class A {
  public class YourGroup {
    // let inner class be creatable by A only
    internal YourGroup() {}

    public string test2 {get; set; }
  }

  // you have create the group (i.e. class)
  private YourGroup m_Group = new YourGroup();

  public string test { get; set; }

  public YourGroup folder {
    get {
      return m_Group; 
    }
  }
}

A a = new A();
a.test = "";
a.folder.test2 = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the use of nested classes

```
public class A
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    public YourGroup folder;

    public A()
    {
        folder = new YourGroup();
    }

    class YourGroup
    {
        public string test2 {get; set; }
    }

}

A a = new A();
a.test = "";
a.folder.test2 = "";
```

However it's not really a group like you say, it's just a class in another class. Your nested class is only visible in the class where she's declared.

But it's not a real solution, I think that if you have to group properties, maybe you have to create a new class (nested or not according to your needs).

**EDIT :**

Moreover you should instanciate the property "YourGroup" in the parent class constructor.

Comment: you have to create `folder` instance before `a.folder.test2 = "";`